# Why only a part of pods in a deployment starts successfully?

Tags: asp.net, kubernetes, .net-core, azure-aks

I am deploying a dotnet app to AKS (Azure Kubernetes Service).

I do not know why but only a part of pods runs as expected while other pods throw a runtime exception and fail. I think the kind of exception does not really matter but in fact it is "System.IO.FileNotFoundException:  Could not load file or assembly ..." thrown at program startup time. The container image is okay and all assemblies are there and running pods prove that.

What are possible reasons of such behaviour?

Comment: How does it go when you run the docker container on local machine with only docker?

Comment: @Jonas locally it works okay.

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor no updates. This error gone away after I did clean rebuild of the app :(

Comment: Could you clarify what is the problem right now? Did behavior of your pods change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so it was my mistake. One of assemblies was referenced with `PrivateAssets="All"` in a `.csproj` file so this dependency was not propagated and required DLL was not copied to the output directory during the build process.